# Unknow length of Http Response

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

We know that in Java EE servlet/jsp, client can obtain one http response for one http request. I want to implement something that has unknown length of http response. I want the server keep on pushing the data for the client after the client has sent the first http request. In that case, I don't want to use AJAX, because AJAX is quite heavy weight.

For example, I want to create a webpage that can retrieve Log Message from the web server, the Log message could be sent by the web server when a Log message is generated from another module (so in this case, time interval is unknown, we assume that regular timer checking is not perferable here). The log message is appended to the web browser which mean web browser cannot refresh, example:

Log 12:00 pm .....
Log 12:03 pm .....
Log 12:04 pm .....
    .
    .
    .

How am I able to do that by sending one http request only and retrieve the http response continuely?

---

@dystroy

Do you mean that, I can flush the printwriter multiple time(when there is new log data) before the end of doPost/doGet?

please ignore the syntax error! I didn't use IDE.

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp){

    PrintWriter pw = resp.getWriter();

    pw.println("<html><body>Testing for the streaming.</body></html>");
    pw.flush();


    /*
    The syntax could not be correct, please focus on logic.
    This while loop check the log sent by web server is finised or not and flush the data to the 
    client, after that the javascript will change the content of the inner Html. Is the logic below
    valid?
    */
    while(!log.finish()){
        pw.println("document.setInnerHtml("+log.newLog()+")");
        pw.flush(); 
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you always can use long http answers and flush them periodically, it works, at least until there is a short problem on the network. You dont HAVE to send the length of the answer in the HTTP header.

Correct solutions are either to do some pulling with ajax or to use websockets, which are very light and fast but aren't supported by all browsers (see http://caniuse.com/websockets ).

About the "heavy weight" ajax, note that the cost is essentially the one of an http query+answer. If you're not asking for a latency smaller than 100ms and have normal connections, you'll find that ajax is reasonably fast (prefer the use of servlets over jsp). Just don't encapsulate your log in a too heavy format.

Comment: Hi, I cannot add the code here, could you help me check the code above? Whether it is similar to what are you saying.

Comment: I didn't test it but your code seems correct. Did you try it and had a problem ? As I try to explain this approach does work but not very well, especially with a bad network or if you stop writing for a long time.

Comment: I will try it when i am home later. By the way, should i set the Connection to be "Keep Alive" as suggested by the another commenter.

Answer (score 0):

Surely you need to consider using `keep-alive`.

It allows the client to reuse an existing connection to read data from the server continuously. Below, just copied the example from link listed below.

```
try {
    URL a = new URL(args[0]);
    URLConnection urlc = a.openConnection();
    is = conn.getInputStream();
    int ret = 0;
    while ((ret = is.read(buf)) > 0) { // here it try to read response using existing connection.
      processBuf(buf);
    }
    // close the inputstream
    is.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    try {
        respCode = ((HttpURLConnection)conn).getResponseCode();
        es = ((HttpURLConnection)conn).getErrorStream();
        int ret = 0;
        // read the response body
        while ((ret = es.read(buf)) > 0) {
            processBuf(buf);
        }
        // close the errorstream
        es.close();
    } catch(IOException ex) {
        // deal with the exception
    }
}
```

Use the technique shown above for loading the log file.

Here is a nice explanation on this: [Persistent Connection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/net/http-keepalive.html)

---

Another option is just simple, consider making `Ajax Request`.

Comment: Thank for the article.

How am I going to try the same thing in servlet/jsp? I am not able to link the article to how could I achieve that in servlet/jsp. Can give me more clue?